# Bash script - make sure there is always N processes launched on slurm

Tags: shell-script, slurm

**Task**

Out of a list of M jobs/commands to launch on remote machines with the `srun` command, make sure there's always N tasks running or requested (N<=M), until all M jobs have been launched.

**Motivation**

(Included as it may give rise to other suggestions). I have to run a set of simulations and I currently do it with a two-step process. Both steps are based on a `MSTR_FILE` containing the basic information about the simulations:

1. Step One: based on the contents of `MSTR_FILE`, create the necessary directories and files for simulation
2. Step Two: based on the contents of `MSTR_FILE`, now launch a job for each entry in the file

The basic loop for Step Two looks something like this:

```
for d in $(cat $MSTR_FILE | cut -d " " -f 1);do
   cd $d
   srun -p My_Queue $(cat sim_command_file)&
   cd ..
done
```

This works fine, however my simulation setup (`MSTR_FILE`) ends up having between 50 and 100 entries, possibly more. Such loop just goes through the full list and grabs resources until the end of the list itself. In a shared resources environment, this is not really desirable :)

**My partially working solution**

I came up with a modification of the script that basically `wait`s until a certain number of jobs have been completed. The relevant part of the script looks like this:

```
N=10
swp_list=($(cat $MSTR_FILE | cut -d " " -f 1))
cnt=0
list_size=$(#{swp_list[@]})

while [ $cnt -lt $list_size ];do
   for i in $(seq 0 $N);do
       ix=$(($cnt+$i))
       if [ $ix -lt $list_size ];then
          d=${swp_list[ix]}
          cd $d
          srun -p My_Queue $(cat sim_command_file)&
          cd ..
       fi
    done
    wait
    ((cnt+=$N))
done
```

This approach seems to work fine, as far as I could test it, in the sense that only `N` jobs are launched at a time. However, it also has a serious drawback: it happens that not all jobs out of the `N` requested starts at the same time. Some of these jobs wait some serious time before being allocated a node. Even if that wasn't the case, it is possible that some simulation tasks require longer than others, even significantly.

My partially working solution does not cope with any of that: it just waits until ALL jobs in the `N` packet has finished. What I would like to have is, however, that there's a sort of `queue` which is always filled with the next job in the `MSTR_FILE`, so that no time is wasted.

Comment: I don't understand. The whole point of systems like slurm is that they manage a queue of jobs and allocate resources. Why are you trying to script this instead of setting up limits on the slurm side?

Comment: Because I don't know what/how to do it - Do you have any pointers to that? I would also think it's a better idea to manage it on the slurm side. BTW, if I don't use scripting, I can launch the sims from a GUI (cumbersome for other aspects): there, the `N` jobs at a time concept is available, but implemented on the sim software side, not on slurm.

Comment: I don't know this particular queuing system, but I would just talk to the sysadmin managing it and ask. It really seems like a waste of your time to try and do manually what the system is designed to do for you. I mean, you could do this easily enough using [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), but if you're already using SLURM that just seems like wasted effort.